# ContextMenu difference in Focus behaviour from Menu

Tags: wpf, menu, focus, contextmenu

I would like a context menu to behave in the same way as a main menu with regards focus.

For example if keyboard focus is in a listbox and I hit F10 to take me to the main menu and navigate through the menus with the arrow keys then the current item in the listbox remains highlighted. However if I right click on an item in a listbox which pops up a context menu then the listbox item looses focus and is no longer highlighted.

Following is some example XAML which demonstrates the behaviour.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" >
                <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Item 2" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Item 2" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ContextMenu}">
            <ListBoxItem Content="List Item 1"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="List Item 2"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="List Item 3"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="List Item 4"/>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried setting Focusable="False" on the ContextMenu and MenuItem's within the ContextMenu, then I can right click on a ListBoxItem and highlight the MenuItem's without the ListBoxItem loosing focus. But, if I try to navigate the ListBoxItems with the up and down arrows then the current item in the listbox changes since the listbox still has keyboard focus.

I'm trying to emulate the behaviour Windows 7 Explorer where the user can pop-up the context menu in the list view and select an menu item with keyboard or mouse while any items selected in the listview remaining highlighted.

Any help much appreciated.

Regards,
Joel Gordon.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  Still drives me nutz that MSFT made the context menus steal keyboard focus.  They should've left it at the control, then delegated it to the related context menu. That way we'd still have focus on our control.